# $.ajax POST not working correctly php

Tags: php, json, jquery

Hi i'm trying to get this with jquery ajax but don't know if i'm doing it correctly...
Really tried everything and basically had to look at jquery.ajax for dummies but still not getting it to work...

```
function addMix(mix) {
    alert(mix);//Here I get my array of int's
    var myArr = JSON.stringify(mix);
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "add.php",
        data: myArr,
        success: function(data) {
            alert("Success: " + data);
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(x,y,z){
            alert("Error: " + x + ", " + y + ", " + z);
            console.log(x, y, z);
        },
        complete: function(data){
            alert("Complete: " + data);
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
 }
```

the php:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
include "con.php";

$mix = json_decode($_POST);

foreach($mix as $index => $val){
$temp = array();

foreach($temp[$index] as $key => $value){
        array_push($temp, $value);
    }
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO mg_test(value)
    VALUES('$temp')";

mysql_query($sql);

echo json_encode($temp);

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Only thing im getting in return is,
alert(mix) = 2,1,3,2

Success: null

Complete: [object Object]

And I get nothing in the DB...

Could anyone point me in the right direction? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$temp` is an array, isn't it? I am not sure how you are trying to insert an array into database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending data to ajax call wrongly. Donot use JSON.stringify(), instead send request parameters like this.

```
type:"POST",
dataType: "json",
url: "add.php",
data: { "requestData": mix },
success:function(data){
  console.log(data);
}
```

In PHP file. get this as

```
$mix = json_decode($_POST['requestData']);
```

Comment: Hm responseText shows "null" in console... maybe wrong with the php?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you do `JSON.stringify(mix)` in the `$.ajax` call?

You can just put the object / array or what it is there!

**Here's a fixed JS:**

```
function addMix(mix) {

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "add.php",
        data: { mix: mix }, // <--- this
        success: function(data) {
            alert("Success: " + data);
            console.log(data);

        ...
    });
}
```

---

And in **PHP**, you must use

```
$mix = json_decode($_POST['mix']);
```

instead of:

```
$mix = json_decode($_POST);
```

---

Also, I am pretty sure this query won't work:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO mg_test(value) VALUES('$temp')";
```

`$temp` is an array - you will have to build the query of it, not just put it there and hope it will magically work. It won't.

Comment: Ok, thanx... It was mostly for testing... console log still showing "null" on responseText, will look thru the php...

Answer (score 1):

Based on $.ajax documentation:

> The data option can contain either a query string of the form
>   key1=value1&key2=value2, or an object of the form {key1: 'value1',
>   key2: 'value2'}.

Just skip the stringify and pass the object as it it in the data field.

Comment: Tried without the stringify but only got parsererrors, anyways, got it working now.. thx..

Answer (score 0):

dont alert an object `alert("Complete: " + data);` it (as you see) returns [Object Object]. so what says the `console.log(data);`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see your objects while using

```
console.log(data);
```

It would be much better readable in Google chrome console.